# Customizing configuration for Flyway 10.0

Tags: kotlin, flyway

In a Kotlin project, we have had this override in version 9.x:

```
@Profile("local")
class FlywayConfig : FlywayConfigurationCustomizer {    
    override fun customize(configuration: FluentConfiguration?) {
        configuration?.pluginRegister?.getPlugin(PostgreSQLConfigurationExtension::class.java)?.isTransactionalLock = false
    }
}
```

But when upgrading to 10.x, there is no longer a pluginRegister() method on FluentConfiguration.

Does anyone know how to accomplish the same in the new version?

Comment: Hmm, the behaviour you're experiencing seems really unexpected to me... https://javadoc.io/doc/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/latest/org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration.html (currently version `10.2.0`) clearly has a `getPluginRegister` method specified (which should be usable as the synthetic property `pluginRegister` as in your code). Sorry I can't provide more help here